Using the api can I install an app into an org?
https://developer.kustomer.com/kustomer-apps-platform/docs/registering-and-updating-apps
Can I make a POST to 'https://api.kustomerapp.com/v1/apps/available' to say install app id "abc123" into my org? Or is this endpoint just for creating private apps not installing public apps?
